# gradle sync failed when use android.support.library

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle, android-appcompat

I want to add android.support to project:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
        jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication2_gradle26_3.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

and when sync the gralde this error fired

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Error: [E:\AndroidExamples\MyApplication2-gradle26-3\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\26.0.0-alpha1\AndroidManifest.xml:21]
> >     Invalid instruction 'overrideLibrary', valid instructions are :
> >     REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT

the project sync successfully when i add appcompat-v7:22.+ but not when want to add appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
i tried to update gradle but IDE errored 'u cant use this version'
my IDE is IntelliJ 13.1.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the Android Plugin for Gradle.

Change:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
```

with:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Also there is no reason to use an alpha version of appcompat. Use the latest stable version of the support libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I want to know how to find gradle:2.3.3 related to which zip file in https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Comment: @Masoudkhanjani Here you can find more info: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html. You should use the gradle distribution 3.3 or higher.